# How do I search by multiple tags?

Tags: spotlight, finder-tag

I am able give files multiple tags, but I can't figure out a way to search by multiple tags. The current search syntax in Finder/Spotlight is to use the `tag:<some_tag_name>` query, however trying to search by multiple tags is not clear.

I have tried these options:

1. `tag:<tag0>,<tag1>`
2. `tag:<tag0> <tag1>`

For example, I have 3 files - foo, bar, baz - and 2 tags - alpha, beta. `foo` is tagged with `alpha` and `beta`, `bar` is tagged with only `alpha`, and `baz` is tagged with `beta`.

I have listed several scenarios which should underscore my objective:

1. A search of `tag:alpha,beta` should only return `foo` since it's the only file with both tags.
2. A search of `tag:alpha` should return `foo` and `bar`
3. A search of `tag:beta` should return `foo` and `baz`

This should be a simple feature included but I can't quite figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I finished writing my own question, I tried another combination, `tag:<tag0> tag:<tag1>`, and it worked! Seems like it's an implicit "AND" when you use it like this.

You can also apply boolean logic in Spotlight/Finder:

- `tag:<tag1> OR tag:<tag2>`
- `tag:<tag3> AND <tag:4>`
- `NOT tag:<tag5>`

Comment: If we wanted to do the OR in the search criteria UI do you know what to choose from the 2 dropdowns? E.g. Name matches?

Comment: @malhal I am not quite sure I understand your question. Are you asking on how to search by tags AND a specific string or text in the file name?

If so, something like this works:

`(tag:alpha OR tag:beta) "some-text-here"`

Comment: @malhal: okay I think by "search criteria UI" you are referring to the search bar in "Finder". What I have found to work is to just type in the exact query and to ignore the dropdown:

`tag:alpha OR tag:beta`

returns files tagged with either "alpha" or "beta" in Finder

Comment: Hi, not the search bar but the edit criteria UI with the combo boxes and add button, eg https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2015/05/search3-100587379-large970.idge.png